# assign link to drop down menu

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql

i have a question and i'm looking for the simplest solution! So i have this database project and i will be using php. the think is that we are required to to this with this language that we are not very familiar. Anyway, suppose i create a drop down list (list of type of cuisine for instance) using  postgresql (look code below for illustration). my drop down list works just find but how in the world i can add a feature such that they can click on whichever cuisine they want and i redirect to a new page with corresponding restaurants (i will once again have to get from the database. the code below is not really important but ill post it so you can have an idea. sorry for being too long.

```
 <form action="index.php" method="post">
<select name="****" id="****">

<option>Select book</option>
      <?php
$conn_string = "host=########################################";
            $dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string) or die ('Connection failed'); 
            $query = "SELECT name FROM db.typeofcuisine";
            $result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);

                              while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
                                {
                                        echo "<option value=$row[name]>$row[name]</option>";
                                }
                                pg_close($dbconn);

  ?>
```

Also i actually want this form to be assign to a link (not just a select option). what i mean by this is that i will have a link, when clicked then i display the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to set link to your drop down menus, see `select` on change event where value is your database selected `restaurant_link` for corresponding `restaurant` name

```
 <form action="index.php" method="post">
<select name="****" id="****" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">

<option>Select book</option>
      <?php
            $conn_string = "host=########################################";
            $dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string) or die ('Connection failed'); 
            $query = "SELECT name,restaurant_link FROM db.typeofcuisine";
            $result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);

            while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
             echo "<option value=$row['restaurant_link']>$row['name']</option>";
            }
           pg_close($dbconn);

  ?> 
</select>  
</form>
```